# working with proxy server and remote server with common database?

Tags: java, proxy

I am a noob to the proxy server and its working. I have made an online judge for organizing programming competition as my college project. At present it works on single system and i have used multi-threading to process more than one solution checking.But i want to extend it so that along with multithreading more than one server is used to check the solution for speed up (as sites like spoj, codeforces etc do). But i dont have any idea on how to do all these. After searching a lot i came to know about proxy servers and got some idea that this server is used to get the client's request and this server than maps to other remote servers using load balancing and then remote server can be used to process the request. But i am not getting how to do all this.

The overall thing is:
The user will submit the code, this code is then put into a queue and then in the back end i have written java code to read from queue and then to check the code and the result is then put into a table.The front end keeps waiting till the result is feeded into the table from the back end. The front end then shows the result as send by the back end using that table.

I also have to show the results of all submissions to a specific problem to all the users. But if i use proxy and remote server than i also need a common database for all these to retreive all submissions, my submissions etc. to be shown to the user.

Please some one guide me, I will be really grateful to you.

Thanks a lot.