# Too many sql connections error : due to long polling

Tags: mysql, long-polling

I have designed a coding platform just like Spoj and Codeforces for competitions to be organised in my college on *LAN*.

I have used long polling there so that any announcements from the Admin can be broadcasted to all users with a **JavaScript** alert message. When anything is posted on the forum then the admin also gets a notification.

But for just 16 users (including the 1 Admin) accessing the site, the server went down showing `too many sql connections`. I restarted my laptop (server) and it continued for a while, then again went down; giving the same error message as before.

When I removed both long-poll processes everything continued smoothly.

**Server-side** code for long-poll:

```
include 'dbconnect.php';

$old_ann_id = $_GET['old_ann_id']; 
$resultann = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT cmntid FROM announcements ORDER BY cmntid DESC       LIMIT 1");

while($rowann = mysqli_fetch_array($resultann)){
    $last_ann_id = $rowann['cmntid']; 
}

while($last_ann_id <= $old_ann_id){
    usleep(10000000);
    clearstatcache();

    $resultann = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT cmntid FROM announcements ORDER BY cmntid DESC LIMIT 1");
    while($rowann = mysqli_fetch_array($resultann)){
        $last_ann_id = $rowann['cmntid']; 
    }
}

$response = array();
$response['msg'] = 'new';
$response['old_ann_id'] = $last_ann_id;
$resultann = mysqli_query($con, "Select announcements from announcements where    cmntid = $last_ann_id");
while($rowann = mysqli_fetch_array($resultann)){
     $response['announcement'] = $rowann['announcements'];
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: What is your setting for the max number of connections? If the number of concurrent users you have doing long polling is close to that then you are likely to run out of connections and would probably be best off disconnecting from the db between polls. On the other hand you could have an issue where you are triggering multiple polling scripts for each user, each of which has a connection.

Comment: @Kickstart: what should i exactly do to overcome this issue. What should be the maximum number of connections allowed ? And what to do for the second case i.e. to overcome "triggering multiple polling scripts......" ? I am totally new to this. Please explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Max connections is defined. Think the default is 100 or 151 connections depending on the version of MySQL. You can see the value in "Server variables and settings" in phpmyadmin (or directly by executing ***show variables like "max_connections";*** ).

If that is set to something very low (say 10) and you have (say) 15 users you will hit the limit rapidly. You are giving each long polling script its own connection, and that connection is probably sitting open until that long polling script ends. You could likely reduce this by having the script disconnect after each time it checks the database, then reconnect the next time it checks (ie, if your long polling script checks the db every 5 seconds you probably have well over 4.5 seconds of that 5 seconds currently where there is a connection to the db but where the connection is not being used)

However you could have a larger number of connections, but if you trigger the ajax polling multiple times per user, each could have several simultaneous connections. This is probably quite easy to do with a minor bug in your javascript.

Possibly worse if you are using a persistent connections you might leave connections open after the user has left the page that calls the long polling script.

EDIT - update based on your script.

Note I am not sure exactly what your dbconnect.php include is doing. I might be possible to easily call a connect / disconnect function in that include, but I have just put it in this example code as using the mysqlu_close and mysqli_connect functions.

```
<?php
include 'dbconnect.php';
$old_ann_id = $_GET['old_ann_id']; 
$resultann = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT MAX(cmntid) FROM announcements");
if($rowann = mysqli_fetch_array($resultann))
{
    $last_ann_id = $rowann['cmntid']; 
}
$timeout = 0;
while($last_ann_id <=$old_ann_id and $timeout < 6)
{
    $timeout++;
    mysqli_close($con);
    usleep(10000000);
    clearstatcache();
    $con = mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd");
    $resultann = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT MAX(cmntid) FROM announcements");
    if($rowann = mysqli_fetch_array($resultann))
    {
        $last_ann_id = $rowann['cmntid']; 
    }
}
if ($last_ann_id >$old_ann_id)
{
    $response = array();
    $response['msg'] = 'new';
    $response['old_ann_id'] = $last_ann_id;
    $resultann=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT cmntid, announcements FROM announcements WHERE    cmntid>$old_ann_id ORDER BY cmntid");
    while($rowann = mysqli_fetch_array($resultann))
    {
         $response['announcement'][]=$rowann['announcements'];
         $response['old_ann_id'] = $rowann['cmntid'];
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
    echo json_encode($response);
}
else
{
    echo "No annoucements - resubmit";
}
?>
```

I have added a count to the main loop. But it will drop out of the loop whether anything is found once it has executed 6 times. This way even if someone leaves the page the script will only be running for a short time afterwards (max a minute). You will have to amend you javascript to catch this and resubmit the ajax call.

Also I have changed the announcement in the response to be an array. This way if there are several announcements while the script is running all will be brought back.

Comment: i got what u said.. I have posted my long polling code in edit. This code is called again again when a new comment has been posted with settimeout of 10 sec through ajax using another php/javascript code. Can u please help me modify the code.I am totally new with this concept

Comment: also my max_connections is by default set to 151 how much should i set   for smooth connections.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Looking at your code that is a never ending script if no comments are added. It could potentially be hours before it finishes, and with each page refresh you probably trigger another incidence of that script running. I have added a few changes a pasted them above.

Comment: i got the closing connection things. But the timeout counter which you have mentioned the while loop will break after 1 minute but what do to  after that 1 minute if other notifications will come then how will i be able to get that.I dint got that resubmitting thing. Please explain When to resubmit and how to resubmit also when not to resubmit.

# dbconnect.php just contains the connection with my sql

Comment: In your javascript that calls the ajax script you expect a response. Currently when you get a response it is a new announcement which you output. I assume you then call the ajax request again to get the next announcement. With the updated script you merely need to recognise when it is returns with no data and then just do the ajax request again with no need to output any new announcements at that moment.

Comment: okay you mean i have to call in both the cases but when there is no announcement then without updating anything i have to call again and if there is some new announcement then after updating the current total rows i have to call.
If my above statement is correct then whats the need to break the while loop after 1 min becoz i have to call that again ?

Comment: Yes you have the right idea. Problem is that if you do not have the break that script could run for ages. If you have the default limit of execution time (30 seconds) and each loop checking for announcements takes 0.01 seconds (ignoring he sleep) then your script could run for 3000 seconds (50 minutes) before it times out, even if you have left the page that called it / refreshed the page and called it again.

Comment: okay i got it thanks a lot for this. Can you please tell me what should be the max_connections in MySql for smooth conduct. And how to change that default value ?

Comment: You can set it in the mysql.ini file. However there are issues setting it too high, just as too low. If you only keep the connections open for a minimal time it shouldn't be an issue to have it at the default level. For example with my example code above, if the connection lasts 0.1 seconds for each loop (with a 10 second sleep) then each script only has a connection for 1/100th of the time. Thus you could support about 15000 concurrent users checking for announcements.

Comment: actually along with check announcement i have other pages(almost every page in the site) which fetches data from database but they are just one time i mean they dont keep on fetching data like long polling.

Comment: They shouldn't be a problem, assuming a normal amount of users. Their connections will probably only be quickly disconnected. It is scripts running for a long time and holding on to a connection that are likely to cause the most problems.

Comment: Can u help me with this ? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20785472/working-with-proxy-server-and-remote-server-with-common-database)

Comment: Afraid not an area I have any experience of. Sorry. Good luck.

Comment: Its all okay no need of sorry.Really thanks a lot for your help

Comment: due to usleep(10000000) in the while loop, "show processlist" command in mysql shows that connection for 1 minute with command field containing "Sleep", which means the connection gets close after 1 minute before i call this script again using ajax. But if i remove that usleep() line from the while loop, "show processlist" command does not any sql connection, that is expected because it keeps and connecting and terminating the connection in the while loop without the halt for 6 times.

Comment: So, is not better to remove that usleep() line from the while loop so that there are no more connection related to that and the code still works, saving some amount of connections for me which will allow more users to connect at any time ?

Comment: Difficult to say. Connecting to the db does take some time so no point in doing this an too many times. Removing the usleep() I think it will connect and disconnect many times with barely a delay between them. The script above should disconnect the connection just before the usleep(), and reconnect afterwards, so I am not sure why it is leaving the connection open.